# UserWay is updating my span element id to random id am using https://userway.org/ on my app

Tags: .net, .net-core, model-view-controller, accessibility

I added the userway accessibility plugin but it caused issue with my one of span element tag updated its id to random.i debugged it this plugin has a function of generatedRandomId but could not able to prevent it why it is updating my span existing id to new one?

I don't know how to prevent plugin from updating my element existing id exists with room-count of my span tag.
my original html

```
 <div id="rooms">
              <div class="dash"></div>
              <label>Rooms</label> <span id="room-count">1</span>
              <select class="custom-select" name="numBeds" id="selected-beds">
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
              </select>
              <div class="icon" id="beds"><img src="~/images/bed.png" /></div>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down chevron"></i>
            </div>
```

plugin updated html

```
<div id="rooms">
              <div class="dash"></div>
              <label>Rooms</label> <span id="uw5c59b57">1</span>
              <select class="custom-select" name="numBeds" id="selected-beds" aria-labelledby="uw5c59b57" aria-label="rooms" data-uw-rm-form="fx">
                <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
              </select>
              <div class="icon" id="beds"><img src="/images/bed.png" role="presentation" data-uw-rm-ima="un"></div>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down chevron"></i>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm probably going to break in an open door with this comment, but do you really think that a simple front-end plugin can automatically and magically solve all  accessibility issues ? I have just the impression that such companies are selling wind, to stay gentle. Anyway, you should first try to contact them to solve your problem, as nobody here on SO can know what's behind this product.

Comment: To piggyback on @QuentinC's comment.  See also https://adrianroselli.com/2021/09/userway-will-get-you-sued.html

Comment: you may be right sure i will contact them..